# Android 5.0 “updating contact list” error

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, contacts, device-firmware

After updating my **android 5.0** (lollipop) phone (Samsung Note 3 N9005) my contact list couldn't open. When I want to open my contacts there was always a process like "**updating contact list**" and I couldn't open my contacts. Also my Whatsapp contacts were always refreshing when I open whatsapp and click my contacts and it takes long time.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem like below:

1. Go **Settings**->**General**->**Cloud**->**Sync Settings**
2. Tap to "**Sync Contacts**"
3. Then go back **Settings**->**General**->**Application Manager**->**ALL** section
4. Select "**Contacts**" then **Clear Data** and **Clear Cache**.
5. Select "**Contacts Storage**" then **Clear Data** and **Clear Cache** (All contacts removed).
6. Go **Settings**->**General**->**Cloud**->**Sync Settings**
7. Tap to "**Sync Contacts**" to bring your contacts again.